# Objective-C: Expected ']' in macro

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

I have a fairly simple macro that I want to use to log messages. The Macro:

```
#define LogDebug(tag, fmt, ...) [MyLogger logDebug:[NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__] \
function:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) file:@__FILE__ line:__LINE__ tag:tag];
```

And I call it with:

```
LogDebug(@"tag", @"message");
```

The problem: at the beginning of `@"tag"` I get `Expected ']'`, where Xcode points to the `@` sign in the macro call (not the definition).

Important: if I remove the `tag` variable, everything works perfect:

```
#define LogDebug(fmt, ...) [MyLogger logDebug:[NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__] \
function:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) file:@__FILE__ line:__LINE__ tag:@"tag"];
```

and

```
LogDebug(@"message");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro parameter named `tag` interferes with `logDebug`'s parameter named the same way – `tag`. Change the macro to:

```
#define LogDebug(tg, fmt, ...) [MyLogger logDebug:[NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__] \
function:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) file:@__FILE__ line:__LINE__ tag:tg];
```

(i.e. `LogDebug(tag, fmt, ...)` to `LogDebug(tg, fmt, ...)` and `tag:tag` to `tag:tg`).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Classic intro to computer science mistake :)

Comment: Macros are evil, yeah.